# How do I construct an update query using a stored procedure in entity framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6

For instance, to retrieve data, I would use something like this...

```
model.PartnerSummaryTotalViewModel = _db.Database.SqlQuery<PartnerSummaryTotalViewModel>("dbo.sproc_SelectPartnerSummaryTotal  @StartDate = {0}, @EndDate = {1}", startdate, enddate).SingleOrDefault();
```

But since it's an update, **how would I construct the syntax to do the below query in EF**. The t-sql stored procedure is as follows:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sproc_UpdateTrafficPartnerActiveFlag] 
@PartnerID int,
@PartnerActive bit = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE [dbo].[TrafficPartners]
       SET [PartnerActive] = @PartnerActive
     WHERE [PartnerId] = @PartnerID
END
```

Comment: btw, this is done using code first, so there is no EDMX designer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing a update/insert stored procedure with entity framework 4.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981523/executing-a-update-insert-stored-procedure-with-entity-framework-4-1). Still applies.