# Web API, Entity Framework insert stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to learn Web API + Entity Framework. To use stored procedures for database access through Web API.

I've successfully done `get` call with select stored procedure. This is my code:

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
        [Authorize]
        public IEnumerable<spSelUsers_Result> GetUsers()
        {
            using(UsersEntities users = new UsersEntities())
            {
                return users.spSelUsers().ToList();
            }
        }
}
```

But I'm stuck here with insert procedure to create new record.

```
[Authorize]
[Route("AddUser")]
public class Users
{
        public string user_name { get; set; }
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string mobile_no { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string user_pic { get; set; }
        public int strowner { get; set; }
        public DateTime dbtstamp { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<spInsUsers_Result> PostUsers([FromBody] UsersEntities Users)
{
        using(UsersEntities Usrs = new UsersEntities())
        {
            return Usrs.spInsUsers();
        }
}
```

From various tutorials online I managed to get up to here... I don't know how to assign values to parameters and pass them...

Also any suggestions on weather to use `IEnumerable` or anything else..

Currently I'm clueless...please help

**Edit: 1**

Stored Procedure

```
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsUsers]
(
    @user_name nvarchar(50),
    @first_name nvarchar(50),
    @last_name nvarchar(50),
    @mobile_no varchar(10),
    @email nvarchar(50),
    @user_pic varchar(256),
    @strowner int,
    @dbtstamp datetime2
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
INSERT INTO [tbl_users] ([user_name], [first_name], [last_name], [mobile_no], [email], [user_pic], [strowner], [dbtstamp]) VALUES (@user_name, @first_name, @last_name, @mobile_no, @email, @user_pic, @strowner, @dbtstamp);

SELECT user_id, user_name, first_name, last_name, mobile_no, email, user_pic, strowner, dbtstamp FROM tbl_users WHERE (user_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY())
```

SP Mapping:

[image]

Comment: Whether you use web API of anything else isn't relevant. Therefore, you're showing the wrong code. You can't insert a new `User`. So please show the stored procedure and also how you mapped the `User` entity in your context class.

Comment: Updated the question with stored procedure and mapping. Pls check.

Comment: Well, for one, you're returning too much from the sp. EF only needs the database-generated values, if any (as in identity values and/or computed columns).

Comment: OK. I've changed it to return only user_id. Now.?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a database first approach once the procedures have been imported to your model you can just pass parameters as you would with any normal function.

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx

If you are using code first you will need to do things a bit differently.

https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/299/entity-framework-code-first-and-stored-procedures

I hope these links help you out.

Comment: Well I've gone through "http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx" multiple times, but somehow was not getting it properly. Finally done. Final working solution in Answer. Thanks for pointing out to go through that tutorial again. Voting u up.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
                        "EXEC SP_AddUpdateResponse @QuestionID, @UserID, @AnswerValue, @ReviewID",
                        new SqlParameter("@QuestionID", questionId),
                        new SqlParameter("@UserID", 9999),
                        new SqlParameter("@AnswerValue", answer),
                        new SqlParameter("@ReviewID", id)
                    );
```

taken from here : [Executing a update/insert stored procedure with entity framework 4.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981523/executing-a-update-insert-stored-procedure-with-entity-framework-4-1)

Comment: Can you pls elaborate. This seems of way old version's answer.

Comment: You said that you din't know how to assign parameters. This is how you assign parameters. **db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand** will execute the stored procedure.
If there's some specific error that you are getting, let us know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Finally a working solution.
Thanks all for contribution.

```
[Authorize]
        [Route("Add_User")]

        public HttpResponseMessage PostUsers1([FromBody] tbl_users Users)
        {
            using (var context = new UsersEntities())
            {
                var response = context.spInsUsers(Users.user_name, Users.first_name, Users.last_name, Users.mobile_no,
                    Users.email, Users.user_pic, Users.strowner, DateTime.Now);

                var message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, Users);
                message.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri +
                    response.ToString());

                return message;

            }

        }
```